# How to make Gson available at the Android native part of a Flutter plugin?

Tags: gradle, flutter-dependencies

Please consider a freshly created Flutter plugin project: What needs to be put in which gradle files to make Gson accessible at the Android native (java) code?

Putting `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'` at the buildscript dependencies of either `(Project: Android)` or `(Module: library_name)` causes gradle sync to fail with `Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'`.

Replacing `implementation` with `classpath` causes gradle sync to succeed, but Gson isn't accessible in any of the java classes. So, obviously, something's wrong here. Do you have any ideas what or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the dependency needs to be put in `build.gradle` of `(Module: library_name)`. There in android{ }:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    }
}
```